# Stored procedures either finishing for less than a minute, or never

Tags: sql-server-2014

**Background** : the instance was migrated from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014. The old machine had half the memory and CPU.

On the old machine, the procedures were running slower (20-30 mins) but they never froze completely. All databases and objects are 100% copies of the older ones.

**The issue**: I have a couple of parameterless stored procedures that are all taking either a minute or eternity to finish. I am also working with a static set of data (and static queries), as I am doing all testing on a copy of the production database (on the production server). Meaning that there are no other queries against this DB, and the table data is not changed. Unfortunately, for security reasons, I cannot post a full query, but I will explain what the stored procedures do and where they all freeze:

All stored procedures contain three `UPDATE` statements and a couple of correlated subqueries for each of the three `UPDATE` statements, that do calculation. The logic is as follows:

- Statement 1: `UPDATE` three columns in all rows based on various filters
- Statement 2 and 3: `UPDATE` same three columns based on same filters as above, with the exception of one, and maybe most importantly, only UPDATE rows where a value of a particular column is NULL (it can be calculated as NULL from the previous UPDATE).

I will provide this little snippet:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = CASE 
                 WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 
                       FROM STUFF (+ various joins) 
                       WHERE rate = 1)
                    THEN something 
                    ELSE something2
              END
```

This is the same for all three updates, all three columns, except rate is 2 and 3 for the second and third batch respectively.

Now the strange issue is, statement 1 is always completing in about 30 seconds. If the stored procedure freezes, it is always on statement 2.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Create additional indexes, rebuild the ones I have, update statistics. Create filtered index for the "WHERE IS NOT NULL" filter on Statement 2 and 3
2. Set the compatibility level to 100
3. Force the query to use the cardinality estimater of SQL Server 2008 R2
4. Force the query to run with different MAXDOP settings - 0,1,4,8,16,28 (we have 28 physical cores with hyperthreading, so 56 logical)
5. Set up all kinds of traces - the only thing I am getting is the wait_info - it is always either CXPACKET for MAXDOP>1 or SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD, both of which are normal.

Looking at the execution plans, the most consuming operations are the couple Lazy Table Spools. The "Rate" column which is the differentiating filter for the UPDATE statements (besides the IS NULL predicate) has 8000 rows with value 1, 7000 for value 2 and 10000 for value 3.

I am really out of ideas at this point, due to this strange behavior. Please share any suggestions you have!